# not able to update the UI

Tags: php, javascript, header

I have a test.php page with a button, clicking on which calls a javascript function.

contents of test.php 
button calling myfunct()

contents of test1.php 
a div with an id="message"

function myfunct(){
window.location('page.php');
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Updated message";
}

contents of page.php is
header('Location:http://test1.php');
exit;

Now the problem is that, it is getting redirected to the required webpage, but after that it is not executing this code 'document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Updated message";'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is b/c the code after a redirect does not get executed on the new page.

What you could do is pass the message along as a get parameter like so.

test.php

```
function myfunct(){ window.location('page.php?message=[put message here]');
```

page.php

```
 header('Location: http://[some_page].com/?message='.$_GET['message']);
```

Then on the final page get the message using `$_GET['message'];` and put it somewhere on the page.

Remember to validate if a variable exists in the $_GET array, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run javascript from test.php on the page you're redirecting to (page.php). When `window.location('page.php')` is called, the browser *immediately* stops executing scripts on test.php and starts loading page.php. In order to run javascript on page.php, you will need to include it in that file.

If you need to pass in data from test.php (for example, "Updated message") you can do it as a get parameter by redirecting to window.location("page.php?message=Updated%20message").

Answer (score 0):

This will not work. Here is why:

1. When you call window.location, your browser is redirected to page.php. As a result anything happening on test.php is discarded.
2. When page.php redirects you back to test.php, it is considered as a brand new page; it does not remember state

Am not sure what you are looking to achieve but there are many workarounds. Here is a simple one:

test.php

```
function myfunct(){ 
<?php
session_start();
if (!empty($_SESSION['updated'])) {
$_SESSION['updated'] = '';
echo "window.location('page.php'); ";
} else {
echo 'document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Updated message";';
}
?>
}
```

page.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['updated'] = true;
header('Location:http://webpage...');
```